# Prevent clicking outside a range of columns in a table

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is that a user can only click on specific columns in a table. In the example in the fiddle for example only on the 2nd till the 15th column. The first two weeks in a time registration module.

I was trying with :lt() function but that only works on the first row it seems.

http://jsfiddle.net/KvdM/FxmbB/1/

Comment: any reason you can't filter them in javascript after the click event?

Comment: @xception: I was kind of hoping it could be done with some fancy selector.

Comment: try my latest answer, via fancy css selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check the [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the td to see if it's between 2 and 15 - adjusting the numbers as you need.

```
$('#sch').on('click', 'td', function() {
    var col = $(this).index();
    if (col > 1 && col < 16) {
        alert('clickable row = ' + col );
    } else {
        return false
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jJpnr/

Comment: Thanks! I changed the if criteria to `if (col >= 1 && col < 15) {` though to have it working like I want it to: http://jsfiddle.net/KvdM/FxmbB/8/. Marked.

Comment: Question is: which option is most performant? This one or the one from @xception? Performance, even with a very large amount of rows is of the essence.

Comment: I would think the delegation is more efficient.. xception is binding an event handler to every clickable td.. with delegation you are only binding one event handler to listen for the event

Comment: Very good question, I'd like to know the answer too but unless you have an insanely large amount of rows I think there wouldn't be any penaly with either... mine only registers the event handler for the matched rows while this other one calls javascript for any click on any row, but unless the user can make a huge amount of clicks in a very short time there shouldn't be any significant penalty with this solution, mine however might be slower because it registers very many event handlers, but if that has any impact on performance  depends on the browser side implementation alone

Comment: @XIII Alternatively you could still do your selection filtering with css with my solution :) would look like `$('#sch').on('click', 'td:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+16)', function()`...

Comment: heres a jsperf of binding vs delegation http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-delegate-jquery and another http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/4

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via a fancy css selector: demo http://jsfiddle.net/FxmbB/12/

Modify your function as below

```
$(function() {
    addRow();
    addRow();
    addRow();
    $('#sch td:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+16)').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});​
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure it out as well :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this fiddle instead http://jsfiddle.net/FxmbB/6/ ?
Basically I just moved the event handling to the declaration side and registered the event only on the proper cells.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/FxmbB/7/

Check the index of $(this). E.g.,

```
$('#sch').on('click', 'td', function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        if ($(this).index() >1 && $(this).index() < 16){
            alert("OK. You can click on that");
        }
});
```

Comment: It seems preferable to me to only make one call to the index() function for performance hence why I marked the other answer as such.